# I cannot find an Open File Dialog a Visual Studio 2022 WPF project

Tags: visual-studio-2022

In previous editions of Visual Studio I could get an OpenFileDialog by creating a reference to System.Windows.Forms. In Visual Studio 2022, when I click on Add and choose Reference, I can't find a reference to System.Windows.Forms. What is going on?

Comment: I also cannot figure this out. Win32 and System.Windows.Forms aren't there.